# Push different View Controllers using segue ios 5

Tags: ios5, uistoryboard, pushviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am developing app using storyboard. I have AccountTable in which I have 6 sections & each section contains 1 row. Sections are :- Profile,settings,FAQ,Privacy,Terms,About. Now I created 1 Protype cell in table view through storyboard & added PUSH segue from **this cell** to different view controllers for each section & given unique names to each segue. Now when I tap on Profile it works well. But When I tap on other than Profile, still it pushes Profile view controller. Why ?

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Segue Identifier:- %@",segue.identifier);
}
```

NSLog is ALWAYS logs "ProfileSegue" (segue identifier for Profile).

What should I do ? Do I need to instantiate every view controller depending on row selected & then call

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe consider `performSegueWithIdentifier:` when you detect which one you want rather than "instantiate every view controller".

Comment: @PhillipMills: I have used `performSegueWithIdentifier:` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. But it always pushes ProfileViewController.

Answer (score 0):

in this method

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Segue Identifier:- %@",segue.identifier);
}
```

you have to check with each identifier.based on which you have to insatatiate the viewcontroller..push it...